# Como inserir um valor extenso em uma tabela em uma coluna do tipo varbinary?

Tags: sql-server, tsql, varbinary

Uma tabela tem uma coluna varbinary(max), eu preciso que ela tenha uma entrada com 400MB de dados nesta coluna.

Como eu crio estes dados?

A instrução Insert tem que ter os dados por extenso ou posso usar um loop ou uma função que gere estes dados?

Comment: De **onde** (campo de tela, arquivo) vêm os dados e por **qual meio** (procedure, código) você vai inserir na tabela?

Comment: Eu vou usar o SQL Management Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resposta de [Martin Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20543246/how-to-insert-100-mb-without-making-a-100-mb-insert-statement)

```sql
INSERT INTO [YourTable] (YourFileColumn)
VALUES      ( CAST(REPLICATE(CAST(0XFF AS VARBINARY(MAX)), 
                         100 * 1024 * 1024) AS VARBINARY(MAX)))
```

Answer (score 5):

Você pode utilizar uma função [OPENROWSET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190312.aspx), exemplo:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Tabela(NomeArquivo nvarchar(100), Arquivo varbinary(max));
GO

INSERT INTO Tabela(NomeArquivo, Arquivo) 
   SELECT 'Texto.txt' AS NomeArquivo, * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Arquivo.txt', SINGLE_BLOB) AS Arquivo;
GO
```

[Referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053564/upload-a-file-to-a-varbinary-with-sql-management-studio)

Answer (score 2):

Amigo, embora eu não esteja exatamente respondendo a sua pergunta da forma como você espera, eu acho que colocar uma coluna com até 400Mb por registro no banco de dados não parece ser uma boa ideia.

Eu colocaria apenas uma URL no banco de dados e disponibilizaria estes dados pesados em algum lugar da internet ou intranet acessíveis por meio da URL cadastrada. Isso também permite que você possa distribuir o acesso a estes arquivos, migrá-los, compactá-los e reutilizá-los sem depender do banco de dados para fazer coisas que não são a finalidade dele.

Comment: Guardar um blob como esse no BD em geral é uma péssima idéia e pode dar problemas de performance. Melhor maneira é guardar isso num arquivo (provavelmente já é um arquivo) e no BD guardar uma referência ao arquivo (link, path, etc)